# Autocompletition in eclipse pdt in codeigniter for doctrine 2 models

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter, autocomplete, doctrine-orm

I'm writing a project using codeigniter 2 framework with doctrine 2 as ORM using eclipse PDT. I would like to know if there is a way to have the autocompletition working for the doctrine 2 Entities classes (the ones located in \application\models\Entities folder) I managed to have that working CASUALLY only once, so i know it's possible, now i'm wondering how to get it always working or what i'm doing wrong.

To be clear let's suppose we have this controller:

```
class Main extends My_Controller {

    function index() {

        $casualAccount = $this->doctrine->em->find('Entities\Account' , 1);
        $casualAccount-> **AUTOCOMPLETITION NOT WORKING HERE**
        $this->load->view('welcome_message.php');

    }
}
```

and we have this model in `\models\Entities`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Entities\Account
 */
class Account

{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $Mail
     */
    private $Mail;

    /**
     * @var string $Password
     */
    private $Password;

    /**
     * @var string $Type
     */
    private $Type;

    /**
     * @var string $First_name
     */
    private $First_name;

    /**
     * @var string $Last_name
     */
    private $Last_name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set Mail
     *
     * @param string $mail
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setMail($mail)
    {
        $this->Mail = $mail;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Mail
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMail()
    {
        return $this->Mail;
    }

    /**
     * Set Password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->Password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->Password;
    }

    /**
     * Set Type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->Type = $type;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Type
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->Type;
    }

    /**
     * Set First_name
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->First_name = $firstName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get First_name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->First_name;
    }

    /**
     * Set Last_name
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     * @return Account
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->Last_name = $lastName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Last_name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->Last_name;
    }
```

Update.
Manix comment is helping out a little bit. It's possible to declare in the class a variable telling of what class it will be using the following syntax:

```
class Main extends My_Controller {
    /**
    * @var Entities\Account
    */
    var $casualAccount;

 ....

}
```

This could help a little bit but it's still far from the automatic autocompletition eclipse should be capable of.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess if I a understand. I have never use Eclipse PDT, but should use annotations in inlines variables when it is not clear. The code below helps to the IDE what type of var `find()` function returns, because this function generate a entity dynamically. There is not an specific type returned.

```
/** 
 * @var $casualAccount  Entities\Account
 */
$casualAccount = $this->doctrine->em->find('Entities\Account' , 1);
$casualAccount-> **AUTOCOMPLETITION SHOULD WORK AT THIS POINT *
```

> *The annotation above is telling to the IDE that `$casualAccount` is type of `Entities\Account`.*

That is the reason that not always the autocompletition is avaliable. Take a look:

```
$this->load->library('Foo');
$this->foo-> /* nothing to show */
```

Autocompletion does not work here because the class reference itself is generated dynamically even you had documented it.

Comment: Your comment is helping out a little bit, the question has been updated